# Fibonnaci Sequence with Callback in Javascript

Tags: javascript, callback

Trying to learn javascript and callbacks. What am I missing here?
**EDITED**

```
var fibNumber = function(n, callback)
{
  if (n < 2){
    return 1;
  }else{
    return function(n-2) + function(n-1);
  }
  callback(n)
}
var n = console.log(prompt("An integer please: ");
fibNumber(n, function(n)
{
  console.log(n)
});
```

Comment: You never call the callback

Comment: Okay, I'd replace the first:   
    console.log(result);  
with  
    callback(result); ?

Comment: What do you think `a, b = b, a + b;` does? Did you mean `[a, b] = [b, a + b];`? Also, it seems a little odd to pass in those numbers as arguments - I'd expect maybe a single argument, `n`, that means "give me the *n*th Fibonacci number". What is your function supposed to actually do?

Comment: Yes, I had no clue apparently. I've since edited it, but it's still not quite right.

Comment: Dramatically changing the code you're asking about...not really fair to people who answer. If you want live help debugging, an IRC channel is a better format than Stack Overflow where it's about [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) questions that are useful to other people beyond just yourself....

Comment: I think you should add some information about callback. This is currently confusing.

Comment: Awesome. I actually went through and did it all in python to get used to it. I'll post the javascript soon.

Answer (score 1):

Not able to understand what you are trying to accomplish by passing values of x and y.

If you just want to print fibonacci series for the first N numbers I have written this code.

```
var fibNumbers = function(n, callback){

    var series = [];

    var temp;

    for (var i = 0; i <= n; i++){

        if(i == 0 || i == 1){

            temp = 1;

        }else{

            temp = series[i-1] + series[i-2];

        }


        series.push(temp);

    }

    callback(series); //calling the callback here with argument series array containing the series

}

fibNumbers(30, function(result){

    console.log(result); //will console log the series

});
```

Comment: Your effort is good but just works good once. if you repeat you'll get something irrelevant.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? @mortezaT

Comment: Call it again with even the same number will show the error. You push every value to array without checking if that exists.

Comment: Check my edit. It works fine now for your case also. I get what you are saying, that if I call this function twice one after the other it displays wrong results. That was because the earlier array was still in memory with prev series

Comment: Also there is no need to calculate the series every time.

Answer (score 1):

If you want callback to be called after final calculation and get the fibo series up to that number then this would be one of your ways to go:

```js
function fibo(n, callWithSeries) {
  fibo.series = fibo.series || [1];

  fibo.f(n);
  callWithSeries(fibo.series.slice(0, n + 1));
  return fibo.series[n];
}

fibo.f = function(n) {
  if (fibo.series[n])
    return fibo.series[n];
  if (n < 2)
    return (fibo.series[n] = 1);
  return (fibo.series[n] = fibo.f(n - 1) + fibo.f(n - 2));
};

var res = fibo(6, s => console.log(s));
console.log('result: ', res);

res = fibo(2, s => console.log(s));
console.log('result: ', res);
```

Comment: There is some problem with the logic, your code is not giving the desired output

Comment: I changed it without test. Check it now now.

Comment: Also, I did not get one thing. You said there is no need to calculate the series every time. Even in your code, it is calculating on every function call (its doing the entire process again). Will be great if you can elaborate on that?

Comment: @RahulArora Yes, I tried to change my code because of that. But after your error report I rolled back my changes to consider the right way when I have enough time after work(maybe tonight).

Comment: @RahulArora I think this would be better.

Answer (score 0):

What has changed:

- Named function `fibNumber` - not necessary.
- `fibNumber` works as closure for `callback`
- Named function `f`. The origin function for calculate the fibonacci number.
- This function is called and then returned. The part where the recursion starts.
- Inside `f` a check is made and `callback`is called. Then the rigcht call of `f` (`function` is not a name for a function) is made with `n - 2` and `n - 1`. the result is retuned.
- You try to return a result of `console.log` instead of `prompt`. This does not work. Split the two part in two and assign the numerical value to `n`. Then make the output.
- Call `fibNumber` with the callback and output the result.

```js
function fibNumber(n, callback) {
     function f(n) {
        if (n < 2) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            callback(n);
            return f(n - 2) + f(n - 1);
        }
     }
     return f(n);
}
var n = +prompt("An integer please: ");

console.log(n);
console.log(fibNumber(n, function (n) { console.log(n); }));
```

Answer (score 0):

Some issues:

- As you always execute a `return` statement before reaching the call of `callback`, that will never get executed. So, do not return, but store the result in a variable, then call `callback` and then return that value.
- Calling `function` is not correct syntax, you'll want to call `fibNumber` instead.
- When you call `fibNumber` recursively you don't provide the `callback` argument. This is OK, but you should then test whether you have received this argument before caling `callback`. Otherwise you will get an error on calling `undefined`.
- You have a missing closing bracket in the statement where you prompt for the input.
- `console.log(prompt(...))` does not return the input value, at least not in all browsers. Perform `console.log(n)` separately.
- You don't convert the input to a number: input received via `prompt` is always a string. Without this conversion the `n < 2` comparison in the function will never be true, and so you would get into an infinite recursion. Cast the input to a number with the `+` unitary operator.
- Not an issue, but it is confusing that in your main code you use `n` both for the input and the output. It is better to use a different variable name for that.

Here is your code corrected:

```js
var fibNumber = function(n, callback)
{
  var result; // for temporary storage of value to be returned
  if (n < 2){
    result = 1;
  }else{
    // You cannot call "function", you need to call "fibNumber"
    result = fibNumber(n-2) + fibNumber(n-1);
  }
  // Only call callback when it was provided
  if (callback) callback(result);
  // also return it:
  return result;
}
var n = +prompt("An integer please: "); // cast input to number
console.log('input: ', n); // don't use console.log to get `n`.
fibNumber(n, function(result) // use different name
{
  console.log('result: ', result)
});
```